# ffmpeg carrierwave-video always returns "unknown encoder libfaac"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ffmpeg, carrierwave, libfaac

I can give ffmpeg videos to convert via command line, and it converts them happily, but when I ask it to convert things in rails, it returns "Unknown encoder libfaac" no matter the video I give it.

I call it using this line:
process encode_video: [:mp4, resolution: "640x480"]

I've already spent hours trying to (unsuccessfully) compile ffmpeg with libfaac on Windows, but now it just seems ridiculous, because not everything I pass it is even aac. What's going on?

Comment: Does your ffmpeg build include `--enable-libfaac --enable-nonfree`? This is doubtful (due to `--enable-nonfree`) unless you compiled ffmpeg yourself. Why not use a different AAC encoder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it! For some reason it was always using libfaac. I fixed this by adding audio_codec: "aac", custom: "-strict experimental -q:v 5 -preset slow -g 30" to the arguments of encode_video.

Comment: How did you added it?

Answer (score 5):

In uploader/video_uploader.rb add these lines

```
version :mp4 do
   process :encode_video=> [:mp4, audio_codec: "aac",:custom => "-strict experimental -q:v 5 -preset slow -g 30"]
end
```